# Flask-Toastr installation

Tags: python, flask, anaconda, jinja2

I was looking something similar to Bootstrap Alerts for using as **flash** message and came up with this - [Flask-Toastr](https://github.com/wiltonsr/Flask-Toastr). I tried to import it but saw that it's not present so thought of installing it but got no command for installing via `conda`. Can anyone provide me the command for installation ?
Or can you give a better flash message display style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just implement this natively. Flask supports a [Flashing with Categroies](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/#flashing-with-categories)...

You could pass the bootstrap class name as the category string:

`flash(u'You are about to delete everything!', 'alert-danger')`

Then handle this in the template.  This is with Bootstrap 4.3's [syntax for alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/alerts/)...

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
  {% if messages %}
    {% for category, message in messages %}
      <div class="alert {{category}}" role="alert">
        {{message}}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

This saves on introducing another dep for something simple.

Comment: I am currently using bootstrap alert but looking to try something new so I came up with this

Comment: @BarefacedBear The `u` in front of the string was intentional.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals) for an explanation.

Comment: I wish to use bootstrap toast instead of alerts. I replaced the contents with code for toast but does not seem to be working. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If a package is not available from conda or Anaconda.org, you may be able to find and install the package via conda-forge or with another package manager like pip, as stated in the [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages).